# Android/java change RSS enclosure String maybe regex

Tags: java, android, regex

```
 <enclosure length="30367" type="image/jpeg" leadimage="true" caption="aaa" url="http://link1.jpg" />

 <enclosure length="30367" type="image/jpeg" leadimage="false" caption="bbb" url="http://link2.jpg" />
```

how i can change in a string, all this line:

```
 <enclosure length="30367" type="image/jpeg" leadimage="true" caption="aaa" url="http://link1.jpg" />
```

to:

```
<enclosure>image/jpeg\ntrue\naaa\nhttp://link1.jpg</enclosure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these tags always follow exactly this format, and attributes will never contain escaped quote characters, then you might get away with

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?x)<enclosure\\s+\n" +
    "length=\"\\d+\"\\s+\n" +
    "type=\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+\n" +
    "leadimage=\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+\n" +
    "caption=\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+\n" +
    "url=\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*\n" +
    "/>", "<enclosure>$1\r\n$2\r\n$3\r\n$4</enclosure>");
```

But there is surely a better way to achieve this using an XML parser.

Comment: SAXParser is only for <item>value</item> , thats why i need this

Comment: @lacas: What exactly is not working? Is it not matching anything, not matching correctly, not replacing correctly? Is there an error message? Which one? Did you use it on the exact text quoted in your question? It's working in RegexBuddy; I don't have Java installed, so I can't test it directly.